# Property ... does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ...'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I changed my .js file to a typescript file .tsx. I have the following function defined within the file:

```
function MyCard(param1: ObjectDto, toggleFunction: any) {}
```

I am using this function in another .tsx file like this

```
<MyCard param1={param1Value} toggleFunction={myToggleFunction} />
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Type '{ param1: ObjectDto; toggleFunction: (index: any) => void; }' is
>   not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ObjectDto'.   Property
>   'param1' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ObjectDto'.

This worked fine before changing to the Typescript format. 
How can I fix this for Typescript?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Components have only one parameter which is the `props` object, therefore your function should look something like this:

```
function MyCard(props: { param1: ObjectDto, toggleFunction: any }) {}
```

or

```
type Props = { param1: ObjectDto; toggleFunction: any };

function MyCard({ param1, toggleFunction } : Props) {}
```

The type system is trying to match the properties with the first parameter of your function, which is of type `ObjectDto`. That's why you get error

> is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ObjectDto'

Comment: Hi @Sulthan thanks for your reply This works but I am getting a proxy object instead of the input value. The proxy object for param1 contains [[Handler]]:Object
[[IsRevoked]]:false
[[Target]]:Object how can I access these properties to get the input value?

Comment: Something like `param1.target.value`?

Comment: well I can't access target like this. What I didn't mention is that param1 comes from an observable mobx list.

Answer (score 9):

Did you make an interface for your component "MyCard"?

Like this:

```
interface MyCodeParams {
    param1: ObjectDto
    toggleFunction: (param: any) => void
}
```

Also, i think `toggleFunction: (param?: any) => void` is the right type because your function may have parameters so you should type your function like this.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, the solution for me was to add the type to the React.FC:

Instead of:

```
type Props = {
    bar: string[],
    buzz: number[]
};

const Foo: React.FC = (props: Props) => {
```

I needed:

```
type Props = {
    bar: string[],
    buzz: number[]
};

const Foo: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
```